# Button with selector for background color - when clicked the background color is extending out of the button

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles

To begin with.. the **button is added dynamically** through code and hence cannot apply the styles in xml.

I have few buttons in my activity and i am using a selector to change the background color. The button also has a "shape" attached to it, for border.

image_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/dark_grey" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/light_grey" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />

</shape>
```

button_background_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border"/>

</selector>
```

Now when i click on the button, the background color, changes just fine. But, the background color is extending beyond the button's size. I am not sure where it is happening.

Please refer to the images below...

Before clicking the button :

[image]

After clicking the button :

[image]

I think the color is extending into the padding or something, but i am really not pretty sure, why this is occuring.

Comment: instead of using a color for your pressed state, you should be using another xml drawable (a replica of your shape, but with a blue color)

Comment: @ArtooDetoo, thanks for the help.. its working. If you can post your comment as an answer, i will accept it

Comment: Done (with example, just in case) - ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border_blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border_dark_grey" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border"/>
</selector>
```

And just add these drawables:

**image_border_blue**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/light_grey" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

**image_border_dark_grey**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/dark_grey" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/light_grey" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create another shape using those color you used in selector...suppose for `Blue` color...create shape named `btn_pressed.xml`...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/blue" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />

</shape>
```

Then place this shape in place of `@color/blue` in the `selector` as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_grey" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image_border"/>

</selector>
```

Follow same process for `@color/dark_grey`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I already got it worked with Artoo's suggestion. Thanks for your help